# "We also recently" or "We recently also"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, adverb-position

Title says it all. The sentence is

> We also recently started playing other games.

or

> We recently also started playing other games.

Which is preferable?

Comment: Also, we recently started playing other games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither choice is wrong. In my opinion its matter of emphasis.

We also recently started playing other games, puts emphasis on additional games played.
We recently also started playing games, puts emphasis on when additional games are played.